# How do I input files to linux executable?

Tags: linux, bash

Here is part of my linux bash script. I need to input some command line arguments to `./AAAAA` executable, but it does not see them. When I wrap them up with `<<end .. end`, it shows me an "unexpected EOF" error. I've tried to put all input files around `..` - didn't help either. I am running out of ideas.

```
while [ "$month" -le 9 ]
do
            while [ "$day" -le 31 ]
            do
                            "AAAA_15-0$month-$day_text.ff"
                            xargs ./EXECUTABLE <<EOF
                            "AAAA_15-0$month-$day_text.ff"
                            "AAAA_15-0$month-$day_text"
                            "AAAA_15-0$month-$day_text.det"
                            ZZZ.txt
                            XXX.txt
                            CCC.txt
                            VVV.txt
                            BBB.txt
                            EOF
                            mv "AAAA_15-0$month-$day_text"*"."* "15-0$month-$day_text"
                            day=`expr $day + 1`
            done
            day=`expr $month + 1`
```

done

Comment: We don't really know how your `./AAAAA ` executable works, so it's hard to say.  Does it have any documentation ? Or do you have its source code ?

Comment: What you have is in fact not an argument, it's data redirected to the `stdin` (standard input stream). So your executable should read it from the `stdin` stream.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `xargs`:

```
xargs ./AAAA <<EOF
XXXX.ff
XXXX.det
CCCC.txt
BBBB.txt
NNNN.txt
MMMM.txt
LLLL.txt
EOF
```

Comment: The problem is that my filenames are prone to change, since they are inside a cycle. I just simplified it in my question....

Comment: Your question should contain enough information to understand your problem. Can you edit it?

Comment: My bad. I put all script there now. EOF sollution gives me *here-document at line 20 delimited by end-of-file.*

Comment: Without being picky, you should not drop in your whole script nor should you simplify the example too much (so that it is missing information). You simply need to create a little example that demonstrates your problem, and just that.

Comment: About your problem, the ending `EOF` needs to be placed *at the very beginning of the line* (meaning position 0, even if that might look odd for you)

Comment: I've shortened the description. Will know for the future. 
Thank you for your help - seems to work now.

Comment: Cool! You are welcome. Trust me, the right, short example gives you good answers on SO pretty fast.

Comment: Thanks for the pointer on `EOF` at comment[#5](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/41189079/how-do-i-input-files-to-linux-executable#comment69578873_41189230). If auto-indenting is enabled, this would mean that an error would creep in accidentally which is very difficult to detect.

Comment: Probably a cleaner and more readable solution would be to create a function which output's the filenames and takes day and month as a parameter and then pipe that to xargs. Like this `filenames "$day" "$month" | xargs ./AAAA`

Answer (score 0):

When you use `<<EOF`, the `EOF` has to be at the beginning of the line, it won't be found if it's indented.

```
while [ "$month" -le 9 ]
do
    while [ "$day" -le 31 ]
    do
        "AAAA_15-0$month-$day_text.ff"
        xargs ./EXECUTABLE <<EOF
        "AAAA_15-0$month-$day_text.ff"
        "AAAA_15-0$month-$day_text"
        "AAAA_15-0$month-$day_text.det"
        ZZZ.txt
        XXX.txt
        CCC.txt
        VVV.txt
        BBB.txt
EOF
        mv "AAAA_15-0$month-$day_text"*"."* "15-0$month-$day_text"
        day=`expr $day + 1`
    done
    day=`expr $month + 1`
done
```

You can instead use `<<-EOF`. This allows it to be indented, but the indentation **must** be <kbd>Tab</kbd> characters, not spaces.